# Insert statement with random generated number

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-insert

What I'm trying to accomplish is to assign a 5 digit number to a row in the table and insert that value with column value to a different table.

For example, this query returns all the rows that I would like to assign a 5 digit random ID:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(ExternalAgentId) FROM lOGS_V WHERE EXTERNALAGENTID <> ''
```

Currently it's returning `4600` rows. NOTE* `ExternalAgentID` is `varchar(50)`

What I need to do is assign a random 5 digit number between `10001` and `39999`. Once I generate the number insert it to the table with `ExternalAgentId` from previous query to another table.

Here's the approach I took:

```
DECLARE @randAgentID int;
DECLARE @AgentID int;
DECLARE @MIN INT;
DECLARE @MAX INT;

SET @MIN = 10001
SET @MAX = 39999

SELECT @randAgentID = ROUND(((@MAX - @MIN -1) * RAND() + @MIN), 0)

SELECT @AgentID = InternalAgentID FROM VendorAgentIDs where InternalAgentID = @randAgentID

IF @AgentID is null
   BEGIN
      INSERT INTO VendorAgentIDs (VendorID, TRIAgentID) values (SELECT DISTINCT(ExternalAgentId) FROM LOGS_V WHERE EXTERNALAGENTID <> '', @randAgentID)
END

ELSE
   BEGIN
      SELECT @randAgentID = ROUND(((@MAX - @MIN -1) * RAND() + @MIN), 0)
      INSERT INTO VendorAgentIDs (VendorID, TRIAgentID) values (SELECT DISTINCT(ExternalAgentId) FROM LOGS_V WHERE EXTERNALAGENTID <> '', @randAgentID)
END
```

It's generating random 5 digit number correctly. However, I'm having two issues:

1. I have a `syntax error` in my `insert` statements.

   > ...values (SELECT DISTINCT(ExternalAgentId)...
2. If the `randAgentID` exists in the table, it goes to the `ELSE` statement. I know the chances are low, but what if the next `randAgentID` also exists in the table? How can I prevent that?

The table `VendorAgentIDs` has `three` columns.

- ID (autoincrement)
- VendorID (varchar(50))
- InternalAgentID (PK, int)

Any suggestions on how I can resolve the above two issues?

Thanks

*** *UPDATE**

Based on the suggestion, I edited my code. However, I now have a `violation of PRIMARY KEY`.

```
DECLARE @randAgentID int;
DECLARE @AgentID int;
DECLARE @MIN INT;
DECLARE @MAX INT;

SET @MIN = 10001
SET @MAX = 39999


SET @AgentID = 1

WHILE @AgentID IS NOT NULL

BEGIN

SET @AgentID = NULL

SELECT @randAgentID = ROUND(((@MAX - @MIN -1) * RAND() + @MIN), 0)

INSERT INTO VendorAgentIDs (VendorAgentID, InternalAgentID) SELECT DISTINCT(ExternalAgentId), @randAgentID FROM LOGS_V WHERE EXTERNALAGENTID <> ''

SELECT @AgentID = InternalAgentID FROM VendorAgentIDs where InternalAgentID = @randAgentID

END
```

> Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_VendorAgentIDs'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.VendorAgentIDs'.

Comment: When you use `VALUES` you have to hard-code them or use dynamic SQL. You could instead `INSERT..FROM`. You should read the relevant MSDN article on `INSERT`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be this will solve your PK issue

```
INSERT INTO VendorAgentIDs
            (VendorAgentID,InternalAgentID)
SELECT DISTINCT ExternalAgentId,@randAgentID
FROM   LOGS_V
WHERE  EXTERNALAGENTID <> ''
       AND ExternalAgentId NOT IN (SELECT VendorAgentID
                                   FROM   VendorAgentIDs)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO VendorAgentIDs (VendorID, TRIAgentID) values (SELECT DISTINCT(ExternalAgentId) FROM TRI_PORTAL.DBO.SCREENPOPLOGS_V WHERE EXTERNALAGENTID <> '', @randAgentID)
```

Is invalid SQL. However I think you can do

```
INSERT INTO VendorAgentIDs (VendorID, TRIAgentID) SELECT DISTINCT(ExternalAgentId), @randAgentID FROM TRI_PORTAL.DBO.SCREENPOPLOGS_V WHERE EXTERNALAGENTID <> ''
```

As for the possiblity (eventuality) of a collision you should just do a loop. It becomes increasingly inefficient but if it has to be a random number and not an index then, so be it.

```
SET @AgentID = 1
WHILE @AgentID is not null
BEGIN
    SET @AgentID = NULL

    SELECT @randAgentID = ROUND(((@MAX - @MIN -1) * RAND() + @MIN), 0)

    SELECT @randAgentID -- why is this here?

    SELECT @AgentID = InternalAgentID FROM VendorAgentIDs where InternalAgentID = @randAgentID
END
```

Comment: `SELECT @randAgentID -- why is this here?` Ups. I was doing testing and forgot to remove that line. I will test your solution right now and let you know the outcome. Thank you.

Comment: I have updated my post. I used your suggestion, however, I get `violation of primary key` in that table. Any suggestions?

Comment: you need to move the insert to after the loop, so you only insert the new record once you have a randAgentID that doesn't already exist. What Nostromoo is suggesting is you begin the loop, then generate your randAgentID, then try selecting it from the database. If you don't find an AgentID for your newly generated randAngentID it means it hasn't been used before, and then you can insert your new agent.

Comment: @Trent, I think using the debugger, my issue is in the actual `insert` statement. It causes an error `violation of primary key` on the very first `insert` statement. I have not tried yet doing the `insert` after the loop maybe that will help.